# How can Read section on page in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

when scroll the pdf in pdf.js, I want to know what are section in your current read.
is it possible?

like

```
function check(){
  if(currentScroll === section_name){
    console.log(`you're in section ${section_name}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. PDF is opened in another context (program). In order to detect position in the pdf document, your code must somehow communicate with another context, which is not possible on the front end side.

Comment: pdf open on pdf.js